# Elements in a Field of size $27$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I constructed the Field $$F_3[x]/<1 + 2x + x^3>$$ as the question asked to construct a field of size $27$ and I understood everything up to this point.

The solution then says the elements in the field are of form $a+ba+ca^2$
where $a,b,c$ in $F_3$ and $a^3 = -2a-1 = a + 2$

how do you work out the form of the elements and where does the "$a^3 = -2a-1 = a + 2$" come from?

Comment: Presumably you are happy that the elements are of the form $a+bx+cx^2$. Because we are in the quotient we have $x^3+2x+1=0$, or $x^3=-2x-1$. Since the underlying field is $F_3$ we have $-2x=x,-1=2$. The idea is obviously that we use this relation to work out the product of two elements of the field.

Comment: what does "field" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the field are of form $a+bu+cu^2$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb F_3$ and $u^3 = -2u-1 = u + 2$.

Here, $u = x \bmod (1 + 2x + x^3)$. That $ -2u-1 = u + 2$ follows from $-2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

This follows from the Euclidean division for polynomials: every polynomial can be written as $p(x)=q(x)(1 + 2x + x^3)+r(x)$, with $r=0$ or $\deg r\le 2$.