# please ignore this question, does a "field" in "a field of math object" mean a special "set"?

Tags: linear-algebra

originally, I was confused with group, ring and field, so I asked

> "a field of math object" shows up everywhere.
>
> for instance,
>
> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Modular_arithmetic_and_finite_fields) says
>
> > In the terminology of abstract algebra, the ability to perform
> >     division means that modular arithmetic modulo a prime number forms a
> >     field or, more specifically, a finite field, while other moduli only
> >     give a ring but not a field.[98]
>
> wiki also uses [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) to define [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)
>
> > A vector space over a field F is a set V together with two operations
> >     that satisfy the eight axioms listed below. ...
>
> and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787746/660389) talks about `a field of size 27`
>
> intuitively, what is a 'field'?

with @J. W. Tanner's help, I've got some intuition about the concept of a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), In the procedure, I asked some more questions and I've removed them.

Thank you all!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#In_a_unital_magma) for the general definition of an inverse, in particular take a look at the sentence about "two sided inverses".

Comment: If you want to learn about field theory, you'll have to read the definition of a field, and that already answers your question.

Comment: in short, each element in a group and field has an inverse, except the additive identity in a field doesn't have a multiplicative inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You originally asked this question:  does "field" mean something like "set" or "group"?

I will give some definitions and examples, which I hope will aid your understanding, though I just noticed you then changed the question.

A group is a set with a binary operation (such as addition or multiplication) that is closed and associative and there is an identity element that leaves an element unchanged when operated with it (such as $0$ for addition or $1$ for multiplication) and each element has an inverse (e.g., inverse of $a$ is $-a$ for addition and $a^{-1}$ for multiplication).  Examples include integers $\Bbb Z$, rationals $\Bbb Q$, and reals $\Bbb R$ with addition, and non-zero rationals or reals with multiplication.  (Nothing multiplied by $0$ is $1$, so $0$ has no inverse and has to be excluded when the operation is multiplication.)  Natural numbers $\Bbb N$ can be added, but they do not form a group because of lack of additive inverses.

Now we're ready to define field.  A field is a set with **two** binary operations (say, addition and multiplication), where the set with one operation (say, addition) is a commutative group, and the set without the additive identity (say, $0$) is a commutative group with the other operation (say, multiplication), and the latter operation is distributive over the former.  Examples are rationals and reals.  Also there are finite fields, such as integers modulo a prime number.  Integers modulo a composite numbers are not a field, because some integers don't have multiplicative inverses modulo a composite number.  There is a field with $27$ elements, but it's not integers modulo $27$; integers modulo 27 are not a field, because, for example, nothing times $3$ is $1$ modulo $27$.

Comment: I discussed a field with $27$ elements rather than matrices, according to your original post

Answer (score 2):

A field is a commutative ring where every non-zero element is invertible.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you please give a simple and concrete example? for instance, what elements a field of size 3 contains? a link to explain this is also appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the integers modulo $3$ forms a field.

Comment: Invertible means there is something you can multiply $1$ and $2$ by (namely, $1$ and $2$, respectively) to get $1$ modulo $3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner 1 thanks for your comments, in this case, modulo 3 = 1, would you plz give the detail what and how multiply 1 and 2 to get 1 modulo 3 = 1?

Comment: $1\times1\equiv1 \mod 3$ and $2\times 2=4\equiv1\mod3$

Comment: It is in general bad practice on math.stackexchange to keep asking more and more questions buried in the comments to an answer to your original question. If you decide that you want to ask a different question about examples, you could start a new post.